# Distribution of Fourier transform of Gaussian time series

Tags: time-series, probability

Consider a zero mean $p$ dimensional discrete time real valued Gaussian stationary time series $x(k),k=0,1,2,...x(k),k=0,1,2,...$. Consider the Fourier transform of $x(k)$ from $N$ samples:

$X(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x(k)e^{−i\omega k}$. Clearly, $X(ω)$ has a complex normal distribution. Under what conditions would $X(ω)$ be a circularly symmetric complex normal random variable?
Consider $\omega \in \{2\pi n/N\}_{n = \{0,1,...,N-1\}}$.

Possibly useful result: $X$ is a circularly symmetric complex normal if and only if $E(XX^{T})=0$.

Comment: $X(\omega)$ is a **$p$-dimensional** complex-valued time series, that is, each element is a vector of $2p$ real numbers which can be regarded as samples of $p$ different complex normal random variables.

Comment: Is $\omega$ restricted to numbers of the form $2\pi n/N$? So therefore since $X(\omega)$ is periodic iwth period $n$, is $X=(X(0),...,X(N-1))$?

Comment: My understanding was that the covariance matrix of the 2p dimensional vector would be the $E(X(\omega)X^*(\omega)$. However, I am confused due to the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution, where the covariance matrix of the $2p$ dimensional vector has the pseudo covariance matrix ($E(XX^{T})$). So is there a case where the pseudo covariance is a zero matrix?                                                                                @Alex R. Yes $\omega$ is restricted to $2\pi n/N$.